# Express app with Node-sass on Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, express, azure-web-app-service, node-sass

I have a basic node web application using express that has a dependency on the node-sass library.

This is being built on a Win64 server, so during the npm install part of the build it is downloading the x64 version of the binding binary due to the current environment.

When its deployed to Azure App Service it throws a runtime error due to incompatability with the node-sass binding binary, as node runs 32bit in Azure App Service...

> Error: Missing binding
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-48\binding.node
>   Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment:
>   Windows 32-bit with Node.js 6.x
>
> Found bindings for the following environments:
>     - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

When i explicitly check in [the 32bit binding](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/blob/master/win32-ia32-48_binding.node) and re-deploy i sometimes get a 502 gateway error...

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are
>   looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while
>   acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server,
>   it received an invalid response from the content server.

and other times i simply get a 500, but it no longer writes the error to the log.

The app depends on node-sass-middleware package version 0.11 explicitly, which depends on node-sass 4.3.0.

Without any error logs i am at a dead end.  Have you come across this issue before, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We eventually resolved this by swapping out node-sass-middleware for gulp-sass, and also adding an npm rebuild step for node-sass.  The key difference here is that the css is now rendered during the build process via gulp.  Running `npm rebuild node-sass` first would invoke the binding download to the build server (if necessary), and then a separate task would invoke a gulp task to render the css.

The remainder of our problem was due to the fact that the web.config specified app.js as the entry point, but express4 uses the bin/www file, and simply references app.js.  The problem with bin/www being the entry point is that iisnode now uses bin as the working directory, which caused issues with root relative references.

Rather than waste any more time trying to figure out if we could configure a different working directory, we simply moved bin/www to ./server.js and changed the web.config to point to server.js

The express app now runs as expected on azure websites.

Answer (score 1):

I leveraged [Node-Sass Example App](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass-example) to have quick test, used [local git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-get-started#create-and-configure-a-simple-nodejs-app-for-azure) to deploy it sample project to Azure Web Apps, which reproduced your issue.

Via the deployment log:

> remote: Selected node.js version 7.4.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
>   remote: Selected npm version 4.0.5

And according the similar error message:

> Found bindings for the following environments: - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

I specified the node.js version in `package.json` to:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "= 6.9.1",
  "npm": "> 3"
}
```

Then redeploy it to Azure via local git, and the sample works fine.

For your further 500 error, you can try to leverage **App Service Editor** to check the output of your website.

Enter the **App Service Editor** from Azure portal, switch to **output** section by clicking the **show output** button, then click **run** to start the application. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, the app service editor is definitely useful.  We ended up using gulp-sass and running npm rebuild node-sass to download the binding before running npm install.  We also needed to modify web.config to send dynamic requests to bin/www.  We are now stuck on a final issue which is due to the fact that iisnode appears to be running from the bin directory, meaning that any references to files relative to the root of the app such as ./data/stuff.json are not found and result in a 500 error.  This is not ideal - is the only way around this to not use bin/www file?

Comment: It seems that your new issue is complex. There is an entrance of your application like `app.js` or `server.js` in root directory, and we need to configure the `handler` and `url ruler` in `web.cofnig`. As the sample at https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/express/web.config. By the way, I hardly can follow you very clearly in the comment, and your further question seems to be little related to your original question. So I suggest you to open a new question on SO, with more detailed messages about your new issue. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there were 2 issues at play, both now resolved.   Will add my answer to this post.  Thanks for your input, it was helpful